# Can't delete the objects and get reverse_lazy. asking for confirm_delete.html when should redirect to index page

Tags: python, html, django, url, bootstrap-4

I'm pretty new at django framework and following a tutorial. It was going fine until I try to clean my code.

I've already read the documentation of reverse and I'm not getting the use of lazy reverse. When I delete an object in template should redirect me back to `index.html` although I get:

```
TemplateDoesNotExist at /webdeve/dream/4/delete/
webdeve/dreams_confirm_delete.html
```

This is my `urls.py`:

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from webdeve import views

app_name = 'webdeve'

# Dreams

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.IndexView.as_view(), name='index'),

# Dreams/detail

    url(r'^(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$', views.DetailView.as_view(), name='detail'),

# Dreams/detail/add
    url(r'dream/add/$', views.DreamCreate.as_view(), name='dream-add'),

# Dreams/detail/Update

    url(r'dream/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$', views.DreamUpdate.as_view(), name='dreams-uptdate'),
# Dreams/detail/detete

    url(r'dream/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/delete/$', views.DreamDelete.as_view(), name='dreams-delete'),

]
```

my delete `view.py`

```
class DreamDelete (DeleteView):
    model = Dreams
    success_url = reverse_lazy('webdeve:index')
```

and the function at html file:

```
{% for Dreams in object_list %}
            <a href="{% url 'webdeve:detail' Dreams.id %}"><img src={{ Dreams.imagem }}></a>
            <li><a href="{% url 'webdeve:detail' Dreams.id %}"> {{ Dreams.titulo }} - {{ Dreams.objetivo }} </a><li>

            <!--delete BUTTON-->

              <form action="{% url 'webdeve:dreams-delete' Dreams.id %}">
                {% csrf_token %}
                <input type="hidden" name="dreams_id" value="{{ Dreams.id }}" method="post" style="display: inline" >
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default btn-sm">
                  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span>
                </button>
              </form>
        {% endfor %}
```

Thanks for attention!

Comment: i've already tried the template name but sends me back to index page with no objects on it and dont delete the object that ive clicked

Comment: Thank you for the english classes markwalker_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have a dreams_confirm_delete.html in your directory?
As per Django you have to add a template with suffix **_confirm_delete** in your directory. Make sure you add this template in right directory,

```
<form class="content-form" method="POST">
     {% csrf_token %}
     <span>
        Are you sure to delete?
     </span>

     <button type="submit"> Delete </button>

</form>
```

Comment: Thank you man, i had already tried this before and or i kept changing in between 'templante_name' and 'success_url' this time i created a template with your code and used both comands and works like should.
Thank you so much bro, some professors don't get that some people are new at Django and stack overflow is being a teacher for me. Thank you so much for your humility

Answer (score 0):

Your paths are missing the leading start character `^`.

```
url(r'^dream/add/$', views.DreamCreate.as_view(), name='dream-add'),

# Dreams/detail/Update

url(r'^dream/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$', views.DreamUpdate.as_view(), name='dreams-uptdate'),
# Dreams/detail/detete

url(r'^dream/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/delete/$', views.DreamDelete.as_view(), name='dreams-delete'),
```

Comment: kkkk thank you bro that solve some others problems i was having too